# Making a 3 values checkbox with eforms

Tags: forms, eforms

I need to create a "checkbox" that has three different aspects (○,⦿ and ●, I created the icons I needed and imported them with icon-appr). However, I read the whole eforms manual and there seems to be no way to create a 3 value checkbox. The box itself is needed to select a full, partial or inexistent agreement with a sentence; since the form needs to be printed after it's compiled, any solution will do, as long as it's visually correct.
I built the MWE using LuaLaTeX since i need it for other commands, but it should work in PdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{eforms}
\usepackage{icon-appr}

\begin{embedding}
\embedIcon[name=CIRCPLA]{./CIRCPLA.png}
\embedIcon[name=CIRCDOT]{./CIRCDOT.png}
\embedIcon[name=CIRCBLK]{./CIRCBLK.png}
\end{embedding}

\begin{document}
\checkBox[\AP{\N{\On{DottedCircle}{\CIRCDOT}\Off{\CIRCPLA}}}\importIcons{y}]{YesPartiallyNo}{2.5mm}{2.5mm}{Partially} Do you agree with this sentence?
\end{document}
```

Links to the images since inserting them here would make them extremely big:
[Black Circle](https://ibb.co/9bnp0v0),
[Dotted Circle](https://ibb.co/rFQhHTp),
[Plain Circle](https://ibb.co/T22W5Sy)

Comment: pdf doesn't support this.  checkboxes (and radio buttons) have only two states. You will have to design it differently.

Comment: I know pdf doesn't support it, but I can't design it differently since it doesn't depend on me, so I'm looking for a workaround. Maybe there is a way to create 3 different overlaying radio buttons each with a transparent state and another with icons and a Javascript on press that makes the active one cycle between the three?

Comment: perhaps, but it would make you dependant on javascript which isn't supported by many pdf viewers (and also on the behaviour of the pdf viewer how they handle overlapping buttons and appearances).

Comment: You could probably do it using javascript.  See chapter 5 of the eforms manual.

Comment: I will look into it. Overlapping shouldn't be a problem since icon-appr accepts png (so transparency); but i've never programmed anything in javascript. Any advices?

Answer (score -1):

I solved by creating two different overlapping checkboxes and adding instructions; the dot is now independent from the rest.
LaTeX seems ok with overlapping checkboxes, the last you put in is placed in front. I won't mark the answer cause if someone has a better solution he can post it and deserve the mark.

Comment: Can you please show us  a short compilable TeX code for a fast proof?